# center align equation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I try to align a multiline equation, but im getting a large space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


\begin{align}
AAAAAA &\,  yyyyy &=& bbbbbb    \\
A    &\,     y  &=&    b  \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I would like the letters in the second line to be in the center of the above.

EDIT:

The first line stands for a Matrix equation. With Micos solution i now got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[t]{c @{\,} c @{{}={}} c}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0  \\
  0 & 1  \\
  0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} & 
\begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
\end{pmatrix} & 
\begin{pmatrix}
  x\\
  y \\  
  0\\
\end{pmatrix} \\
A      & x     & d      \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: for example the single letter 'A' in the second line should be center to 'AAAAA' from the first line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you looked into using an `array` environment?

Comment: no i havent, but thats not a math environment, right

Comment: Actually, `array` *is* very much the math-mode equivalent of `tabular`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[t]{c @{\,} c @{{}={}} c}
AAAAAA & yyyyy & bbbbbb \\
A      & y     & b      \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up query: To typeset the two versions of the matrix equation you've added to your initial query, I would use nearly the same code as given above, with the exception that I would replace `@{\,}` with `@{}` as the separator between the first and second column of the `array`. This is because, in my not-so-humble opinion..., the spacing between matrix-like environment provided by the `amsmath` package (which provides the `pmatrix` environments) is a bit excessive, especially so for the case at hand. (If you do want the default spacing of the `amsmath` package, just keep the `@{\,}` inter-column specification as per the initial answer.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[t]{c @{} c @{{}={}} c}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix} & 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y\\
  \end{pmatrix} & 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y \\  
    0\\
  \end{pmatrix} \\[4ex]
  A & x & d\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course `mathtools` is not necessary.

Comment: thank you, that looks good. how can i change the vspace between first and second line?

Comment: @ArthurSpooner - I've provided an addendum to my answer to address your follow-up query about typesetting a more realistic set of equations.